# Adapt code inside dokuwiki spoilers style?

Tags: javascript, css

To change selector so it only show/hides when i click the image i put spoiler/ popdown menu directly after .OS image. Right now the popdown is a child of the .OS container, so clicks on it are passed to the .OS click handler.

But the code isn't perfect because when i click the 1st `MAC` both spoilers are opened.

But I want that spoilers are opened *one at a time*

But the main problem is that I can't fix the javascript code properly inside these types of spoilers (dokuwiki class) inside `<td>` tags:

This is the javascript code I use :

```
<div class="dokuwiki">
    <div class="right_page">
        <div class="entry-content">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="./zzzz_files/jquery.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">                                         
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $(".nonjs").removeAttr( "href"); //href is needed for users without JS
                    $('.OS').click(function(){
                        if($(".details").is(":visible"))
                        {
                            $(".details").not(":hidden").hide("slow");
                            return true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $(".OS").not(this).each(function(i) {
                                $(".details").hide("slow");
                            });
                            $(".details").show("slow");
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                });  
            </script>     
            <style type="text/css">
                <!--
                .details {
                    display: none;
                    clear: both;
                    padding: 2px;
                }
                .nonjs{
                    cursor:pointer;
                }
                img {
                    border: 0px;
                }
                -->
            </style>
```

I thought about doing a video to better explain the problem and provide the local version of files for testing code:

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This code works:*

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $(".nonjs").removeAttr( "href"); 
//href is needed for users without JS

 $('.OS').click(function(e){
           if(!$(e.target).parents('.details').length){
                        if($(this).find('.details').is(":visible"))
                        {
                            $(this).find('.details').not(":hidden").hide("slow");
                            return true;
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            $(this).find('.details').show("slow");
                            return false;
                        }
          }
});
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you're asking but here is what I think you want:

When clicking on an image, show the details below it and hide all others. If the details are already visible, hide them. Clicking something inside the details should not affect anything.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4A3FM/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".nonjs").removeAttr( "href"); //href is needed for users without JS
  $('.OS').click(function(){
    var details = $(this).next(".details");
    $(".details").hide("slow");
    if(details.is(":hidden")) {
      details.show("slow");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: mmm..is possible change spoiler without hiding the content of  preceding spoiler? How do I post this code here without creating conflicts with other scripts? http://chilp.it/23911c

Comment: Take out the line that hides all of them before showing one. Then you can add an else case to hide the clicked one if its visible.

Comment: Can u post the code please, i don't understand very well. I try to add `else
 {
  
   $(this).find(".details").show("slow");
   return false;
 }` but doesn't work. When i click 2nd spoiler the first is hiding but i want that first remaning visible when i click 2nd spoiler.

Comment: I have "if details is hidden, show". now add "else hide". Hint: the function you want to use is `hide()` and not `show()`

Comment: but where it should insert? Can u show me with jsFiddle, please?

Comment: No, I can help you figure it out though. Where do you normally put an else block associated with an if statement? This is a simple `if (condition) { do this } else { do this }`

Comment: sachleen, you are american, i'm italian. For you it's trivial, but not for me. I will Ask for help to someone else. God hog..

Comment: This isn't a language problem. I don't want to give it away because you won't learn anything. Take a look at my code, write comments on each line to fully understand it if you need to. Then write pseudocode for what you want to do. There is a method to doing this, not copy/paste and hope for the best. I don't care where you're from, problem solving is the same. From what I see, you aren't even reading the code. I suggest you add code to *hide* something and you ask me why `.show("slow");` isn't working? Really? I'm trying to help you, you could try, too.

Comment: I try, i try and try modifyng code but I suspect that some rules that applied to some nested item `(ie .OS > .details {...})` isn't being applied. I don't understand why. This is the page: http://chilp.it/23911c . Your code solution doesn't work because clicking something inside the details the spoiler hides. the code seems to be right. Can you give me a clue?

Comment: I would change it from `$('.OS').click` to `$('.OS > a').click`. You'll only be able to activate it from the link now but it won't activate when you click anywhere else. The problem is that `.OS` contains everything, the title and the content.. so your click event binds to *everything* as well.

Comment: sigh..`$('.OS > a').click` doesn't work..can you see in this package, please? http://chilp.it/2a65f6 Can u try to modify?

Comment: I can't do that. It doesn't work doesn't help me at all. What doesn't work about it? What happens?

Comment: I can not stand that the spoiler will close itself if I only select the text inside, but I want to keep the motion blur of spoiler..is there an alternative spoiler like this without this code problem? But if u click tabs 1-2-3 the spoiler doesn't close..Why? yet it is within `.OS`

Comment: Try adding [`stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) to the `.details` click event and see if that helps.

Comment: `if($(this).find(".details stopPropagation() ")` like this?